# Perl - Iterating through an array of hashes issue

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

Newcomer to Perl so I suspect there is a simple solution to this but I cannot see it despite extensive Googling.

```
my @special_things = get_special_things(\@allThings);

sub get_special_things {
    my $things = shift;
    my @specialThings;

    foreach my $thing (@$things) {
        if ($thing{special} == 1) {
            push(@specialThings, $things);
        } 
    }
    return @specialThings;
}
```

The array of allThings being passed in is an array of hashes. I am getting an error on the foreach line telling me that 'Global symbol "%thing" requires explicit package name'.

I know this has something to do with referencing the hash value or key but I am at a loss at the minute. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `$thing{special}` means the element with key `special` of hash `%thing`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an array of *hashrefs*, not of hashes. You need to use `$thing->{special}` when when working with hashrefs.